# How to solve sql error -904 in inserting data

Tags: sql, db2, db2-zos

I wanted to write some records say 10000 in database table but got sql error -904 after inserting some records say 2000. I deleted 25 records of old records and than run the program again and this time after inserting 2025 records I got the same error? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please edit your question to add the "reason code", add the "resource type", add the "resource name"  .  These will determine your course of action.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot see these information since DSNTIAR utility returns return-code 4. How else I can see more information about this error?

Comment: How are you invoking the DSNTIAR, how large is your message area, have you tried increasing it ?   https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/11?topic=dsntiar-defining-message-output-area

Comment: What does -904 error mean?

Comment: Unavailable resource

Answer (score 0):

The log of the MSTR adress space of the DB2 instance should show the "unavalable resource" message DSNT501I including the reason code and in case of deadlock/timeout message DSNT375I/DSNT276I will show the offending user/plan.
If you can't access it yourself you could try contacting your DBA.